# Cannot remove deleted account from AWS Organisation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

I have created an Organisation with the following set up:-

```
- Root
-- Acc1 (Management Account)
-- Acc2
-- Acc3
-- Acc4
```

I have deleted `Acc2`, `Acc3`, and `Acc4` over a week ago. However, I still cannot remove them from my Organisaton. I get a `ConstraintViolationException The member account must be configured with a valid payment method, such as a credit card.`

However, I cannot do that as I have deleted them.

Comment: Same issue :/ amazon at its best...

Answer (score 1):

The quick solution is to close the account by clicking on it's name and then in the top right clicking on close instead of remove. After 90 days the account and it's resources are unrecoverable.

This is the info that I got off of amazon after trying to solve this issue for myself. The account needs be a standalone account to be removed from under my org.

That's why I got the `ConstraintViolationException` it then goes into detail about what specifically needs to be added to the account to remove it. In my case:

> The member account must be configured with a valid payment method,
> such as a credit card.

Meaning that the account needs credit card information to pay for the services it may use in the future. Before, the account didn't need that info because it was linked to the credit card of my organization.

You do have the option of signing into that account and adding the info whatever constraint is needed but that's the whole point - That is not my account and I want it removed.

The only other option is to close the account and wait the 3 months for it to be removed from my org. After that I don't care if it's recoverable or not

Refs:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/APIReference/API_RemoveAccountFromOrganization.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_accounts_remove.html#leave-without-all-info
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/close-account.html?icmpid=docs_orgs_console

Comment: There is no option "Close" in the current Console version.